# SSIS error calling Script task in child package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a child package that runs perfectly when executed in isolation. When I call the same package from a Parent package via an Execute Package Task I get the error:

> 0xC000F427 To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.

The parent package also has a script task prior to calling the child and this runs successfully.

Note: I am developing and testing on my workstation.

Comment: Do you get this on your local or on the server? What do you have installed (with versions). To which SSIS versions the packages are configured to run in? Which SSDT-BI you have installed? Do you have a locally installed SQL Server (version, edition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try : Select the Execute Package Task, hit F4 (properties) and change ExecuteOutOfprocess to false. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-package-task 
"If you set the property to True, you cannot debug the package in a tools-only install. You must install Integration Services. "
 Let us know if it worked.

Comment: Yes this worked, incidentally I had other child packages in the same solution where this was already set!!!!